# 2TB Azure Storage account in case of disaster recovery?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, disaster-recovery

I have an Azure Storage account with 2TB of data. For the design of a disaster recovery solution how I can recover it on a remote site with huge data?

Comment: What do you mean with 'on a remote site with huge data'?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Storage has different data redundancy modes to provide recovery in case of a disaster.

> **Locally redundant storage (LRS)** copies your data synchronously three
> times within a single physical location in the primary region. LRS is
> the least expensive replication option, but is not recommended for
> applications requiring high availability or durability.
>
> **Zone-redundant storage (ZRS)** copies your data synchronously across
> three Azure availability zones in the primary region. For applications
> requiring high availability, Microsoft recommends using ZRS in the
> primary region, and also replicating to a secondary region.
>
> **Geo-redundant storage (GRS)** copies your data synchronously three times
> within a single physical location in the primary region using LRS. It
> then copies your data asynchronously to a single physical location in
> the secondary region. Within the secondary region, your data is copied
> synchronously three times using LRS.
>
> **Geo-zone-redundant storage (GZRS)** copies your data synchronously
> across three Azure availability zones in the primary region using ZRS.
> It then copies your data asynchronously to a single physical location
> in the secondary region. Within the secondary region, your data is
> copied synchronously three times using LRS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How i will point to the new endpoint?

Comment: Take a look at the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy